# Using jasmine and chutzpah to test validator jquery

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, jquery-validate, jasmine, chutzpah

How can i test this validation method by using chutzpah and jasmine??

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod('minvalidator',
                function (value, element, params) {
                    if (value.length == 0 && params.mandatory !== "True")
                        return true;

                    if (value.length < params.min)
                        return false;

                    return true;
                });
```

Comment: i haven't found any sample to test a function like this. all sample show how to test dependant funcion.

Comment: I'm very familiar with jQuery Validate plugin but am not familiar with Jasmine or Chutzpah.  Maybe you can update your OP to explain more about what you're ultimately trying to achieve here.  Normally, you'd also have a call to `.validate()` and some HTML markup for a form... the `.addMethod()` method cannot work by itself.

Comment: @Sparky I've been trying to test jQuery validation plugin using Jasmine. Since you're familiar with the plugin, have you unit tested it before?

Comment: Exactly define your idea of "unit testing" as it would apply to a jQuery plugin such as this.

Comment: Like I said in the older comment, you need to declare the custom rule and initiate the plugin with the `.validate()` method, and none of this will work without the associated HTML markup.